# How can I get data from 2 tables in Realm

Tags: ios, realm

I have 2 tables:

Table Question:

```
questionId, questionContent, chapterId
```

Table Choice

```
choiseId, choiceContent, questionId
```

The input is `chapterId` so I want to get an array of object that contain all questions and options that matched to that question.
I am using Realm database and RxSwift.
How can I do this. Thanks you!

Comment: Realm does not have tables in that capacity. We would need to see your actual Realm objects, need clarification on what *The input is chapterId* means and understand the relationship between the objects. Please update your question with the objects, clarify what you're asking and take a moment to review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Realm is NoSQL database, Joins are not supported.
In short, You cannot query on multiple tables using a single query call. Instead, you should use [Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships)